# GSP select tag doesnt work with findAll()

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to show select box in GSP with some values from DB table.
Following code works fine

```
<% List a = test.demo.MyCategory.findAll("from MyCategory where is_deleted = false"); %> 
 <g:select name="myCategory.id" from="${a}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" />
```

But when I try this by writing query directly in tag, it  doesn't work.

```
<g:select name="myCategory.id" from="${test.demo.RecipeCategory.findAll("from MyCategory where is_deleted = false")}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name" />
```

Comment: You shouldn't be making database calls from the view, this isn't PHP. Do the database work in the controller or a service, and pass the data to the view to be rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
<g:select name="myCategory.id" from="${test.demo.MyCategory.findAllWhere(isDeleted:false)}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem are the double quotation marks in the query string.